# Handle MSMQ Send() message fails, not to lose message

Tags: c#, msmq

I've just started to implement MSMQ, and I'm facing a situation that I don't know how to handle.

If I send a message to my MSMQ service, but because of whatever Send method throws an error, how can I handle it in order not to lose this message that was not sent to MSMQ? Are the any non-sent message qeue that I can proccess later on or I gotta handle it storing it in my database?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can't handle that kind of truth.  Just make sure that a human knows so they can take corrective actions.  Depends on their expected skill level, start by not trying to catch the exception to verify there is still a good diagnostic available.  If not then you need to work on *that*.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you looking at MSMQ - it's an old technology and is notoriously tricky to debug and configure. There are better options for a new project.

Comment: @Rikalous what do you recommend me?

Comment: I have used Azure Service Bus and RabbitMQ myself

Comment: @Rikalous thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Send()` method raises an exception then have to assume the message hasn't been enqueued. You will need to handle that yourself and resend it.